# How to send and request data from my view to the backend controller using Angularjs and MVC

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have data about student test scores in a school. I want to show the students data in a page filtered by their class names(class a, class b), and time periods (months, weeks, year).
By periods I mean take the sum of test scores in the current week, month and year.

In my view I have something like this:

```
<div class="list">
                        <label class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                <h3 class="balanced">Period:</h3>
                            </div>
                            <select data-ng-model="period">
                                <option value="week">This Week</option>
                                <option value = "month" selected>This month</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input item-select" data-ng-model="Schools>
                            <div class="input-label">
                                <h3 class="balanced">Schools:</h3>
                            </div>
                            <select data-ng-model="schools">
                                <option value="class a" selected><a href ng-click=" ">Class a</a></option>
                                <option value="class b">Class b</option>
                            </select>      
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="list">
                        <a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="student in students>
                            <h2>{{student.name}}</h2>
                            <div>{{student.score}}</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

And in the controller I have something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Students> Get(string school = "class a", string period = "month") 
        {
         //Logic    
    }
```

My model

```
Student {
    public int id,
    public string class,
    public int score
    }
```

My question is: How to send the data from the view to the controller about my selected values? How to get to this point (string school = "class", string period = "month") from my view?

Comment: You should not be mixing templating (HTML) on both client and server. When you've decided to use Angular, the server side needs to provide ONLY data and not HTML

Comment: I am not mixing the server side does not contain html

Comment: If you have a filter button, then on click of that you can do $http.post request, hit the server and display results on client side?